# Know the time spent by API request in flight - Angular 9

Tags: angular, progress-bar, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to intercept request in angular to know if API is taking more than 5 seconds in flight. If API takes more than 5 seconds then a message needs to be displayed like 'Request in progress, it will take a short while'

I am able to calculate time took by API after getting response as below:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const startTimestamp = +new Date().getTime();
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(
          (evt: HttpEvent<any>) => {
             const endTimestamp: number = +new Date().getTime();
             // get the difference
             const responseTimes = (endTimestamp - startTimestamp) / 1000;
             console.log(`Request took ${responseTimes} ms`);
          }
      )
}
```

However, i want to know the time while request is in flight. Any leads will be apprecited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a `setInterval` would satisfy your question :
(this would check the time spent at the start of the request and current time every 10 ms)

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const t0 = performance.now();
    let interval;

    console.log('processing request', request);
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      const t1 = performance.now();
      const responseTime = (t1 - t0) / 1000;
      console.log(`Request took ${responseTime} ms since start`);
    }, 10);

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log('processing response', ev);
        }
      }),
      catchError((response) => {
        if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          console.log('processing http error', response);
        }

        return Observable.throw(response);
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        const t1 = performance.now();
        const totalResponseTime = (t1 - t0) / 1000;
        console.log(`Request finished: took ${totalResponseTime} ms`);

        clearInterval(interval);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

[demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-interceptor-angular9-9geycp?file=src/app/http.interceptor.ts)